# It is possible to import an env variable and use it in build.gradle?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, environment-variables

I have a mobile application based in react-native.
I'm using react-native-dotenv package to have an environment variables file so i can use in the project.

Now I need to set the targetSDKVersion dynamic (to use version 29 when running the app in staging and version 30 when running the app in production) in the *android/build.gradle* file, so I tried to create an environment variable in my .env file and call it in *android/build.gradle* file, but without success.

Also I tried to use another package to do so (react-native-config) and call the .env variable like this in the *android/build.gradle*:

```
ext {
  ...
  targetSdkVersion = project.env.get('VRIABLE_NAME')
  ...
```

}

But also without success.

Has someone faced an issue like this and can help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: try `System.getenv("VAR_NAME")`

Comment: @PrasadU didn't work either :(